# Extract the text from url which is Pdf

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping, ocr

I want to extract the text from [this pdf](http://www.oagkenya.go.ke/index.php/reports/doc_download/887-nock-ltd). I cannot do this with `pypdf` as the document was scanned.

Comment: Little confused as to what is the problem that you are facing. Can you clarify further

Comment: Yes when you click on this url it download  one pdf document. i want to extract the text from that document. with mine code it prints only [' '][' '][' '][' '][' '][' '][' '][' '][' '][' '] and so on

Answer (score 1):

Your pdf that you want to extract text from is actually just a bunch of scanned photos. Since PdfFileReader and other pdf readers extract text based on the metadata of the document you won't get any results with that (If text isn't already embedded in the PDF, then you'll need to use OCR to extract the text.).

You can use Tesseract for that, Tesseract doesn't ocr pdf's so transform .pdf to .tiff with something like convert:

```
convert -density 300 /path/to/my/document.pdf -depth 8 -strip -background white -alpha off file.tiff
```

Then use tesseract on that file:

```
tesseract file.tiff output.txt
```

Comment: Can you say how can i convert without download url

Comment: You need to save the downloaded pdf in a buffer (as you have in your code) and give it as input to the tesseract ocr api so there's no saving to disk. Problem is you have to use a native api to be able to do that, i'm not really familiar with any native tesseract api's in python but I guess this is a great link to look into: https://pypi.org/project/tesserocr/

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;

public class PDFreader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception

    {

        URL url = new URL("http:/....view.php?fil_Id=5515");
        byte[] response = null;

        try (InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {

            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int n = 0;
            int counter = 0;

            while (-1 != (n = in.read(buf))) {
                out.write(buf, 0, n);
                counter = counter + n;
            }
            response = out.toByteArray();
        }

        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("abc.pdf");
        os.write(response);
        os.close();

        File file = new File("abc.pdf");
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
        PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        String text = pdfStripper.getText(document);
        System.out.println(text);
        document.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: User needs answer in `python`